# S22.Imap.BadServerResponseException - IMAP xm003 BAD [CLIENTBUG] Command syntax error

Tags: imap

Problem with the S22.Imap:

```
xm003 BAD [CLIENTBUG] Command syntax error
```

my Search Condition from the Example:

```
IEnumerable<uint> uids = client.Search(SearchCondition.SentSince(new DateTime(2015, 10, 20)));
```

oll other SearchCondition's work fine. Pls Help.

Comment: What's the actual command sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that S22.Imap is sending an incorrectly formatted date string in the `SENTSINCE` search query.

Since S22.Imap is a dead project, I would recommend switching to my open source [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library instead.

Hope that helps.